# Stop function loop on click

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a loop adding/removing the classes on the .master div:

```js
function loopSlide(){
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("one") }, 0);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("one") }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("two") }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("two") }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("three") }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("three") }, 6000);
  setTimeout(loopSlide, 6000);
}
  
loopSlide()
```

```css
.master div {
  display: none;
}

.master.one div:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}

.master.two div:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.master.three div:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Now I am looking for a way, how to stop the loop by clicking on one of the divs (1, 2, 3).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f51jxck/1/)

Comment: you need to set the timeout into a variable and then clear the timeout - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Comment: A boolean variable which store if the loop is active or not and a click listener on the master's children should lead you to the right direction.

Comment: Also why not just add the same class to the divs to show them, eg just add an active class

Comment: @Pete I just simplified the code to show my problem

Comment: There is something very wrong with the way you are doing things then as you will soon find your code unmanageable and hard to maintain if you need to add more divs due to having repetitive code

Comment: @Pete Mhh, I don't think so, because there are several animations added via css, all depending on the class name of the main div.

Comment: Ok then refer to my first comment and that will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below logic where you can retain class one, two and three and also stop the loop when click on div where you need to clear interval which is saved in a variable

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $master = $('.master');
     var $div = $('.master div');
     var $currentDiv = $('.master div:first');
     $currentDiv.addClass('one');

     var interval = setInterval(function(){
         var $next = $currentDiv.next();
         $master.removeClass('one two three');
         if($next.length>0) {
            $currentDiv = $next;
         } else {
            $currentDiv = $('.master div:first');
         }
         var index = $currentDiv.index();
         if(index == 0) {
           $master.addClass('one');
         } else if(index == 1) {
           $master.addClass('two');
         } else if(index ==2) {
           $master.addClass('three');
         }
  }, 2000);
  
   $div.on('click', function(){
     clearInterval(interval);
   
   });
  
  });
```

```css
.master div {
  display: none;
}

.master.one div:nth-child(1) {
  display: block;
}

.master.two div:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.master.three div:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div >1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but it is important to switch classes with names "one", "two", "three" as there is a deeper logic. I just simplified it, to show my problem. So now, the stop is working, but thee class is not changing anymore :S

Comment: works perfect. And is there also a way to initially start the whole loop by a click on a button new button?

Comment: yes, you can call settimeout inside click handler of the button instead of directly calling it from `$(document).ready..`

Answer (score 1):

`reference = setTimeout()` returns a value that lets you "cancel" the setTimeout's function execution via `clearTimeout( reference )`

Store the value returned by `setTimeout()` then let a click on the `<div>` clear the timeout

```
$('.master').on('click', function(evt) { clearTimeout( reference ); } );
```

---

Another approach would be to store inside a variable if the loop shoud proceed or not. Change the variable when the users clicks. Check the variable before `setTimeout()`

```
var proceed = true;
$('.master').on('click', proceed=false; } );
```

...

```
if( proceed ) setTimeout(...
```

The whole thing becomes

```
var proceed = true;

loopSlide();

function loopSlide(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("one") }, 0);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("one") }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("two") }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("two") }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").addClass("three") }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(".master").removeClass("three") }, 6000);
    if( proceed )
    {
        setTimeout(loopSlide, 6000);
    }
}

$('.master div').click(function (){
  proceed=false;
});
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lz0verb/)

Comment: I liked the second approach, but maybe I am too stupid to get this work: https://jsfiddle.net/b0vxzejh/